# Making floating div like jgrowl

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to do **Floating DIV** like [JGrowl](http://stanlemon.net/projects/jgrowl.html#samples).The position is right bottom.
The `DIV` must be stick that position whatever I scroll the page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS would be very simple for this. You can just do.

```
#growl {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

You'd still have to worry about how different browsers handle it. I would just use the jgrowl plugin with the proper option set.

Comment: May I have more details CSS to same with jgrowl ? eg. background style or something like that.

Comment: You can do it with CSS easily but IE support may be a bit off. You can do border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; and then for the transparency you can use a transparent PNG as the background image or do background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, .7 ); but you'd have to give IE a solid black in this case before that.

Answer (score 0):

In JGrowl there is option **position** to control position on screen. Please check jGrowl Options listed on site

Comment: I don't want to use JGrowl.I want to make my own.No need to close the that div like jgrowl.That div will show when the page ready.This is for show some info: that related with current login user.